# Adding a detailed disclosure indicator to Call out in Annotation.h

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Can you add a disclosure indicator to the call out when creating your annotations?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: rightCalloutAccessoryView